# Expo Camera on Android doesn't work well as on Web

Tags: react-native, camera, expo

I'm developing a React Native app. I'm using Camera-Expo.
When I test it and take a photo on Web, it is saved as 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg....' and it can be saved on cloudinary.com
Though when I test it on my phone using Expo, the photo is saved as 'file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/Experie.....' and it is not saved on cloudinary.com

How can I save the photos I make by phone on cloudinary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ImageManipulator](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator/) from Expo to change the captured file to `base64` and then you can upload it on cloudinary